# Updating an item in Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am kinda new with Laravel (a lot of experience with cakePHP) and I am running into a problem, probably because I am kinda rusted with the cakePHP way of processing requests...

I want to update one item in the database, but some how it updates all rows in the table, instead of just the one sent from the form...

```
public function update(UserType $user_type, Request $request, $id) {
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
    $this->id = $id;
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), ['_method', '_token']);
    $user_type->update($input);
    return Redirect::route('user_types.index')->with('message', 'User type successfully updated!');
}
```

when I print out $id, I get the ID sent from the form. When printing out $user_type, I get the other values from the form.

My question is, how do I set the ID that needs updating? In cakePHP it's with this line: $this->id = $id;

Can anyone please help me out? Because I am now thinking in a circle

Thanks to Abdul, I changed the code a little bit and it now works :)

```
    $user_type = UserType::find($id);
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), ['_method', '_token']);
    $user_type->update($input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to find the user first based on the $id from the request and then try updating that user.

```
$user = UserType::find($id);
$user->update($input);
return Redirect::route('user_types.index')->with('message', 'User type successfully updated!');
```

Comment: You can do the following in that case:
$user->name = $input['name'];
$user->save();

Comment: But you did help me out a lot Abdul :) I changed the code in this and it works fine Now :)

        $user_type = UserType::find($id);
        $input = array_except(Input::all(), ['_method', '_token']);
        $user_type->update($input);